# Get a Lat/Long from a Neighborhood Name

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I have a list of neighborhood names from Rio de Janeiro and would like to get the latitude and longitudes associated with name. [image: Neighborhood Names]

When I type any of the names into Google, it responds with a lat/long tuple as seen below.

[image: Googled Neighborhood Name]

I'm wondering if there's a programmatic way to do this, as opposed to going through, Googling each neighborhood name, and typing the lat/long for the neighborhood. I suspect there may be a way to do this with `ggmap` but any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggmap)
geocode("copacabana")

# Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=copacabana&sensor=false
# lon      lat
# 1 -79.38823 43.64842
```